# Картинка в качестве фона QWidget

Tags: qt, c++

Необходимо в качестве фона виджета использовать некоторое изображение (занесено в ресурсы программы).
Как решить эту задачу? 
Пробовал делать следующее:

```
class WidgetLoading: public QWidget
{
private:
    QBrush *brush;
    QPalette *palette;
public:
    WidgetLoading();
    ~WidgetLoading();
};

WidgetLoading::WidgetLoading(): QWidget()
{
 brush = new QBrush;
 palette = new QPalette;
 brush->setTextureImage(QImage(":/background.jpg"));
 palette->setBrush(QPalette::Window, *brush);
 this->setPalette(*palette);
}

WidgetLoading::~WidgetLoading()
{
 delete brush;
 delete palette;
}
```

Но ничего не появляется. Просто окно с белым фоном. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно это сделать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проверьте, как заданы пути к изображению в файле ресурсов.

Comment: В файле ресурсов source.qrc установлен префикс /.
В нем расположен файл background.jpg. Обращаюсь к нему как описано выше. В чем здесь ошибка?

Answer (score 1):

Свойство виджета `autoFillBackground` нужно выставить в true.

Сейчас попробовал сделать проект из одной формы. В конструктор этой формы вставил твой код. Все работает без `autoFillBackground`. Похоже где-то в другом собака порылась.

Answer (score 1):

Доброго времени суток!

Я бы  на Вашем месте перекрыл у виджета событие рисования `void QWidget::paintEvent(QPaintEvent*)` и в нем бы нарисовал картинку используя `QPainter::drawImage()` или `QPainter::drawTiledPixmap()` (в зависимости от того что нужно) предварительно загрузив ее из ресурсов. Такой способ используется самим Qt в виджете `QSplashScreen`. Кстати можете посмотреть в его сторону, поскольку из приведенного Вами кода, как я понял, именно это Вам и надо.

Answer (score 0):

Я бы посоветовал:
во первых сконвертить картинку в png, иначе придется тянуть за приложением плагины imageformats для jpg.
во вторых использовать css. http://doc.crossplatform.ru/qt/4.5.0/stylesheet.html
Этим способом кстати можно и в дизайнере пользоваться.